# How to do batch sequencing in Mulesoft

Tags: mule-studio

I have multiple batch_step but currently it all starts processing synchronously i.e. batch_step2 should start only if batch_step1 is executed completely.

How to identify whether batch_step1 is finished processing and then start with batch_step2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve with the above logic. Batch processing is meant to process individual records by each batch step. Every record is passed through batch steps sequentially. batch step 2 for a record will be executed only after the batch step1 is completed. As per the mulesoft docs "Note that a batch job instance does not wait for all its queued records to finish processing in one batch step before pushing any of them to the next batch step".

Alternately you can have different batch with only one batch step. This will ensure that batch step 1 is completed for all records first and then next batch step is executed in next batch job.